# how to mount container root directories /mnt , /dev, /opt in kubernetes podspec

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

I want to mount the container root system directories like /mnt, //dev and /opt with kubernetes podspec volumes. Not able to do it.

working docker command used is

docker run -d --network host --name test_container --volume test_volume:/mnt --privileged -v /dev:/dev $IMAGE_NAME

in podspec, i mentioned for container as below:
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /mnt
name: mnt-data
- mountPath: /dev
name: dev-data

volumes:

- name: dev-data
  hostPath:
  path: /dev
  type: Directory
- name: mnt-data

This is not working when i am doing kubectl apply -f podspec.yaml
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: "/mnt/script.sh": stat /mnt/script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown

through docker run command its working fine but failing through kubernetes podspec

Comment: That implies the file doesn't exist on the node the cluster schedule chose for you.  IME it's very unusual to try to set a pod's `command:` to come from a `hostPath:` mount; indeed, since the contents of a `hostPath:` mount depend so much on which node the pod's running on, it's unusual to use it at all.  Can you package your script in an image instead?  Why do you need access to these host directories?

Comment: this is the dockerfile: Expose/57000
RUN mkdir -p /mnt
WORKDIR /mnt
ADD . .
RUN CHMOD +x /mnt/script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/mnt/script.sh"]

Comment: Delete the volume mounts and you should be set; you'll get the `/mnt` from the image containing your script.  (`WORKDIR` will create the directory and you don't need to `RUN mkdir` before it.)

Comment: the /mnt of container should be mount to locally Volumes test-volume through kubernetes pod and should be running

Comment: If the main thing the container is running is in the image's `/mnt`, you do not want to mount anything over that.  I'm also not sure how this relates to the original question of mounting privileged content from an arbitrary cluster node's host filesystem into a pod.